# Is $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \cot \left( \frac{x^2+1}{x+3} \right) $ well defined?

Tags: calculus

Is this limit well defined?
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \cot \left( \frac{x^2+1}{x+3} \right)
$$

Do I have to go $\cos$/$\sin$ or does the fact that as $x$ approaches infinity makes it not a well-defined limit? My understanding is that in order for a limit to to well-defined, it has to reach the same value from the left and the right as well as be finite. Is this correct?

Thank you,
Jen

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Choose two sequences tending to infinity along which $\cot$ converges to different values (hint: use the periodicity of $\cot$).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a well define limit, it has to reach the same value from left and right but the value could be also $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.
In general the limit is not well defined when we can contradict the definition of limit.
In this simple case we can note that $\cot$ is a periodic function so, as in the case of other periodic functions like $\sin$, $\cos$, etc., when $x$ goes to $\infty$ the limit is not well defined.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\cot\left(\frac{\pi x}{2x}\right)=0.$$